# how get char not surround by somechar in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want a regEx that gives me something like that.

```
let regEx = 'get all % and not surround by `% or %`';
let stringName = '`%this is test% for get useful regEx%`';

stringName.replace(regEx,"someChar");

// (?!`)\%\b(?!`) not working
// (?<!`)%(?!`) work but not supported in all browsers.
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'?

Comment: Can you add the expected output?

Comment: Parsing with regex leads to pain.  How do you tell with '%a%b%c%' which of the '%' are the  surrounding ones?

Comment: in this case ` '%a%b%c%'  ` i wanna get all % except '% & %'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first should be a negative lookbehind `(?<!` instead of a lookahead `(?!`

You can omit the word boundary as well.

```
(?<!`)%(?!`)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/LSqFol/1)

Another option is to capture the `%` in group 1, while matching the what you don't want

```
(?:`%`?|%`)|(%)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dCJxGq/1)

Then you can use [replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter) specifying a function as the second parameter.

The function takes argument(s), in this case `m` refers to the full match, and `g1` to group 1.

Test for the value of g1 using `(m, g1) => g1 ? 'someChar' : m)`

If it exists (so there is a group 1 value), return your replacement value.

If `g1` does not exists, return the full match to replace the values  with the same values leaving them the same as they were.

```js
let s = 'get all % and not surround by `% or %`';
console.log(s.replace(/(?:`%`?|%`)|(%)/g, (m, g1) => g1 ? 'someChar' : m));
```

Comment: tnx this work! but my not supported in all browsers -  [check in this](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: @H.jalali I have added another option to use a capture group.

Comment: not working , this captured all % `% %`. I want to get %  except  `% and %`

Comment: @he values you are looking for are in capture group 1 (Highlighted in green on the regex101 link). I have added an example how to do the replacement, the replaced value is `[%]` in the example.

Comment: first tnx ,i want replace % with some char except % have ' before or after --> like "get all % and not surround by '% or %'  ". result -> "get all _someChar_ and not surround by '% or %' "

Comment: @H.jalali Ok I have updated the example, you don't have to reuse the group value, just checking for it will be enough in this case. Then use your replacement value that you want.

Comment: **@The fourth bird** tnx to you i learn something new in this case. i mean this (m, g1) => g1 ? `someChar` : m) . can you get me more information about that?

Comment: @H.jalali I have added an explanation about the code in the answer.